# DynamoDB - Get N random items? (Schema Question)

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Quick background - I want store every possible 5 character base 64 product. So, AAAAA, Afjsfs, 00ZZ0, etc.

I want to be able to grab 1000 of them randomly, then delete them from the DB so they're not used again.

Its trivial to generate and shuffle these. If I store them in an RDBMS, I could use an auto-inc Int ID, the first 1000, then delete the records. Assuming I put them in randomized, that totally works.

I'd like to see if its feasible to accomplish with DynamoDB, or if this problem is best left to RDBMS.

I could use an Int ID as the key, the 5 char string as the value, and do something similar.

Unless I'm misunderstanding, I can't just get walk keys and grab 1000 records can I? I need to provide a key. That sounds fine, except now I have to maintain DB state at the app layer or introduce another table just to keep track of the IDs I've iterated and deleted.

Answer (score 1):

you can do the following:

(1) Each item will have a fixed partition key (that is same partition key value for all item. The exact value does not matter, as long as it is the same for all items, so let's assume it is simply the string `"foo"`).

(2) The sort key will be a something random, for instance a randomly generated 32 bit integer.

(3) the 5-characters base 64 string will be stored in a third attribute (which is neither the partition nor the sort key)

when you want to grab 1000 random items you need to issue a DynamoDB [`query`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) on partition key = `"foo"`. Items returned from a query are sorted by the sort key. Since you chose a random sort key (see (2) above) you will get 1000 random items.

### sort key considerations

the set of all 5 characters base 64 is a space of size `2^30`. Thus your sort key needs to be large enough to store 2^30 items. So, pragmatically picking a random 32-bit int will be enough. However, if you need ensure that the selection of 1000 items is really really random you may want to pick something whose randomness is better than your runtime's random function. For instance, you can compute `sha-384` on the base 64 value that you store and use it as the sort key value. The [max length of a sort key is 1024 bytes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html#limits-partition-sort-keys) so 384 bits is well within the limits.

In particular, do not use UUID as your sort key. UUIDs are typically not that random.

Comment: If the random IDs are sufficiently random, there’s no need for a fixed partition key. You can use the random ID as the partition key and `scan` the table for the first N values.

Comment: @MatthewPope AFAIK there is no guarantee on the order of items returned by scan. since there is no guarantee the DDB impl. may choose some policy which will result in some order which is not that random.

Comment: You are right that there is no guarantee on the order of items returned by scan. However, computers have only *pseudo*random number generators, and unless DynamoDB manages to reverse engineer your random number generator and your seed value, then DynamoDB is not going to de-randomize your data.

Comment: @MatthewPope that's a good point. However, it is possible that DynamoDB's scan order is somehow affected by insertion order. The typical implementation, I assume, will generate the payload (5 characters base 64 strings) in some order (such as `AAAAA`, `AAAAB`, `AAAAC`, ....).